# Cold water smell only in 2 of 3 bathrooms

Tags: plumbing

2 of 3 bathrooms have smell in cold lines only! It dissipates in 1-2 minutes. system has been chlorinated twice.  could it be in faucets?

Comment: What does it smell like, and have you done anything to your water system lately? Are you on well or city water?

Comment: not knowing where this question is going; because honestly, at first blush it doesn't make any sense at all - have you done anything to the sewer or drains? has any plumbing been touched at all (not just water supply)? and.... really, Im just wondering are you sure it is the water and not sewer gasses from drains? (if you get a cup of water does the cup smell?????

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we'd be able to help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.